# How to calculate redshift/scale factor of matter-radiation equality without current density values

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, photons, space-expansion

I am trying to solve a cosmology problem and I am stuck.
Initially, I am given the following assumptions: a spatially flat universe that contains relativistic matter only. I have had to derive the equation for the age of the universe, which I have done, and used it to calculate the age of such a universe at a temperature of T<sub>*</sub>=10^28K, which I also think I have done correctly. (For this last part I have used T=T<sub>0</sub>(1+z), assuming that it holds for such a universe).

However, I am then told to assume that a new non-relativistic species is present, and I am given the matter density over the critical density of that species (dependent on temperature) (  ρ<sub>χ</sub>(T<sub>*</sub>) /  ρ<sub>crit</sub>(T <sub>*</sub>) = 10<sup>-12</sup>), and to calculate the redshift of matter-radiation equality.

I am unsure as to how to proceed. In a spatially flat Universe, then    Ω<sub>r</sub>+    Ω<sub>m</sub>=1 as the cosmological constant has not been mentioned and the non-relativistc component has been introduced from a universe of just relativistic matter (right?). Then the Friedmann equation would simplify to H<sup>2</sup>(a) = H<sup>2</sup><sub>0</sub> { Ω<sub>m</sub>a<sup>-3</sup> + Ω<sub>r</sub>a<sup>-4</sup>}.
I have the value of the scale factor at T<sub>*</sub>, and if Ω<sub>m</sub>=10<sup>-12</sup>, then I also have Ω<sub>r</sub>=1-Ω<sub>m</sub>.

But how can I use this to predict the time of matter-radiation equality, without having current values for the densities (as that is the next question)? Matter and radiation dependence on the scale factor is different, and from here I think it should be quite straightforward, but I am stuck.

I hope I made myself clear, thank you.

Comment: The assumed non-relativistic particle can be assumed to have a much higher rest mass than the relativistic particles. I do not think you are being asked to deal with the origin of these non-relativistic particles. I am also unsure of the meaning of "redshift of matter-radiation equality". Do you have a clear concept of what this is intended to mean?